# req.file is undefined when I upload image using multer and html input form

Tags: node.js, forms, file-upload, postman, multer

I wanted to upload images using nodeJS and multer, so I did the following:

Below is my multer configuration:

```
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({

    //Setting up destination and filename for uploads
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {  
        cb(null, 'uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {  
        cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
    }

});

var upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits:{
        fieldSize: 1024*1024*6,
    }
});
```

Below is my route to upload image:

```
router.post('/designer', upload.single('designerImage'), async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);

    //rest of the code which is not needed for my query
})
```

It works perfectly fine when I POST the file using *form-data* key of type *file* using *POSTMAN*. But when I try to send it using a HTML form input, `req.file` comes out to be `undefined` and no file gets uploaded to the *uploads* folder. Below is my HTML form code:

```
<form action="/designer" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="designerImage">
<form>
```

What is the solution to this problem? I've spend hours but couldn't get to a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multer` [only parses](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage) `multipart/form-data` requests, so you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form

```html
<form action="/designer" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="designerImage">
<form>
```